# Numpy random number generation runs slower after being vectorised

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, random

I have noticed that attempting to speed up numpy code that involves generating large numbers of random numbers by vectorising the python `for` loops out can have the opposite result and can slow it down. The output of the following bit of code is: `took time  0.588` and `took time  0.789`. This goes against my intuition for how to best write numpy code and I was wondering why this would be the case?

```
import time
import numpy as np

N = 50000
M = 1000
repeats = 10

start = time.time()
for i in range(repeats):
    for j in range(M):
        r = np.random.randint(0,N,size=N)
print 'took time ',(time.time()-start)/repeats

start = time.time()
for i in range(repeats):
    r = np.random.randint(0,N,size=(N,M))
print 'took time ',(time.time()-start)/repeats
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO your comarison is not quite fair - what about measuring time for building a 2D array out of a list of 1D arrays?

```
In [127]: %timeit np.random.randint(0,N,size=(N,M))
1.32 s ± 24.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [128]: %timeit np.column_stack(np.random.randint(0,N,size=N) for _ in range(M))
2.73 s ± 135 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: hmm, yeah, I see your point. I edited the code to allocate an empty array of size `(N,M)` inside the `i` loop of the first case and store the random values in the `j`th column of the array and after making that change the first case is slower.

Comment: @RGWinston, it doesn't surprise me ;-) Please take a look at the timing comparison in my answer...

Comment: yes, thank you for your answer! The context is I have some data of length `N` and within the `j` loop I compute `np.var(data[r])` each time. Whereas in the second instance I compute `np.var(data[r],axis=1)` only once. Then in both cases take the mean of the results. I had gotten used to thinking that if you could vectorize a task that would automatically be quicker in numpy.